# In Django, how do I create a serializer that will auto-generate a primary key for a member of my model?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I'm using Django 3, the Django REST framework, and Python 3.7.  I have the following models.  Notice that the second is dependent upon the first ...

```
class ContactMethod(models.Model):
    class ContactTypes(models.TextChoices):
        EMAIL = 'EMAIL', _('Email')
        PHONE = 'PHONE', _('Phone')

    type = models.CharField(
        null=False,
        max_length=5,
        choices=ContactTypes.choices,
    )
    phone = PhoneNumberField(null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(null=True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('phone', 'email',)

...

class Coop(models.Model):
    objects = CoopManager()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=False)
    types = models.ManyToManyField(CoopType)
    addresses = models.ManyToManyField(Address)
    enabled = models.BooleanField(default=True, null=False)
    phone = models.ForeignKey(ContactMethod, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name='contact_phone')
    email = models.ForeignKey(ContactMethod, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name='contact_email')
    web_site = models.TextField()
```

I would like to submit some JSON to create my model, so I created the below two serializers to help me ...

```
class ContactMethodSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = ContactMethod
        fields = ['type', 'phone', 'email']

    def create(self, validated_data):
        contact_method = ContactMethod.objects.create(**validated_data)
        return contact_method

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        if type(data) == dict:
            contatcmethod, created = CoopType.objects.create(**data)
            # Replace the dict with the ID of the newly obtained object
            data = contactmethod.pk
        return super().to_internal_value(data)
...
class CoopSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    types = CoopTypeSerializer(many=True)
    addresses = AddressTypeField(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Coop
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'types', 'addresses', 'phone', 'enabled', 'email', 'web_site']

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        rep = super().to_representation(instance)
        rep['types'] = CoopTypeSerializer(instance.types.all(), many=True).data
        rep['addresses'] = AddressSerializer(instance.addresses.all(), many=True).data
        return rep

    def create(self, validated_data):
        #"""
        #Create and return a new `Snippet` instance, given the validated data.
        #"""

        coop_types = validated_data.pop('types', {})
        instance = super().create(validated_data)
        for item in coop_types:
            coop_type, _ = CoopType.objects.get_or_create(name=item['name'])  
            instance.types.add(coop_type)

        return instance
```

The issue is, I'm not sure how to create my phone and email contact fields without submitting a primary key (I'd like to have that auto-generated).  I created this test to try ...

```
def test_coop_create(self):
    """ Test coop serizlizer model """
    name = "Test 8899"
    coop_type_name = "Library"
    street = "222 W. Merchandise Mart Plaza, Suite 1212"
    city = "Chicago"
    postal_code = "60654"
    enabled = True
    postal_code = "60654"
    email = EmailContactMethodFactory()
    phone = PhoneContactMethodFactory()
    web_site = "http://www.1871.com"
    state = StateFactory()
    serializer_data = {
        "name": name,
        "types": [
            {"name": coop_type_name}
        ],
        "addresses": [{
            "formatted": street,
            "locality": {
                "name": city,
                "postal_code": postal_code,
                "state_id": state.id
            }
        }],
        "enabled": enabled,
        "phone": {
          "phone": phone
        },
        "email": {
          "email": email
        },
        "web_site": web_site
    }

    serializer = CoopSerializer(data=serializer_data)
    serializer.is_valid()
    assert serializer.is_valid(), serializer.errors
    coop = serializer.save()
    assert coop.name == name
    type_count = 0
    for coop_type in coop.types.all():
        assert coop_type.name == coop_type_name
        type_count = type_count + 1
    assert type_count == 1
    assert coop.addresses.first().locality.name == city
    assert coop.addresses.first().locality.postal_code == postal_code
    assert coop.addresses.first().locality.state.id == state.id
    assert coop.enabled == enabled
    assert coop.phone.phone == phone
    assert coop.email.email == email
    assert coop.web_site == web_site
```

but it results in the error below

```
AssertionError: {'phone': [ErrorDetail(string='Incorrect type. Expected pk value, received dict.', code='incorrect_type')], 'email': [ErrorDetail(string='Incorrect type. Expected pk value, received dict.', code='incorrect_type')]}
```

What's the correct way to set up my serializer to create the foreign keys without having to specify an ID?

**Edit:** GitHub repo:

```
https://github.com/chicommons/maps/tree/master/web
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of box, rest-framework serializes relationships (`phone`, `email`) with primary keys.

> Any relationships such as foreign keys on the model will be mapped to PrimaryKeyRelatedField. Reverse relationships are not included by default unless explicitly included as specified in the serializer relations documentation.

source: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#modelserializer

You would normally create `ContactMethod` objects, one for `name` (for instance with id=1) and second for `email` (id=2), before creating `Coop` and then include their id's in our payload. So it would look like

```
{
    // ...
    "phone": 1, 
    "email": 2,
    // ...
}
```

In your case you need to create `ContactMethod` when creating `Coop`. You need to change `CoopSerializer` to accept payload serialized by `ContactMethodEmailSerializer` in `email` field and `ContactMethodPhoneSerializer` in `phone` field.

```
class ContactMethodPhoneSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ContactMethod
        fields = ['type', 'phone']
        read_only_fields = ['type']
        extra_kwargs = {'type': {'default': 'PHONE'}}


class ContactMethodEmailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ContactMethod
        fields = ['type', 'email']
        read_only_fields = ['type']
        extra_kwargs = {'type': {'default': 'EMAIL'}}


class CoopSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    types = CoopTypeSerializer(many=True)
    addresses = AddressTypeField(many=True)
    phone = ContactMethodPhoneSerializer()
    email = ContactMethodEmailSerializer()
```

With this serializers your test payload should be accepted.

In `CoopSerializer.create` method you need to handle creation of `ContactMethod`, similar to what you have done with `CoopType`, you can follow example in docs:
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#writable-nested-representations

Comment: Gave this a go but got the error, "AssertionError: The `.create()` method does not support writable nested fields by default. Write an explicit `.create()` method for serializer `directory.serializers.CoopSerializer`, or set `read_only=True` on nested serializer fields."

Comment: @Dave You need to keep your original `CoopSerializer.crate()` method and handle creating `CoopMethod` objects like you have done for `CoopType` by `pop`ing `types` from `validated_data` and creating `CoopType` objects in `for` loop .

Comment: I'm having a hard time following, you mean like this -- https://github.com/chicommons/maps/blob/master/web/directory/serializers.py ?

Comment: Try to uncomment `phone = validated_data.pop('phone', {})`  and change and uncomment `instance.phone = ContactMethod.objects.create(type=ContactMethod.ContactTypes.PHONE, **phone)`.

Comment: Thanks.  Uncommenting all that stuff results in a "AttributeError: 'collections.OrderedDict' object has no attribute 'phone'" on the line "instance.phone = ContactMethod.objects.create(type=ContactMethod.ContactTypes.PHONE, phone=phone.phone)"

Comment: @Dave Take a close look at my last comment. It is not `phone=phone.phone` but `**phone`.